# Are heat vents better in the corners of your home

Tags: heating

I am doing this for science class and need to search the

Comment: VTC as too broad.  Besides no one here is going to do your homework for you.  This question as written says "do my research for me".

Comment: @Tyson So how did you learn? Ask questions?

Comment: @LeeSam learning is awesome, but this question says "do my homework for me".  If I had asked the equivalent question I would have said "here is what I know so far" and discussed, then said "my observation is that I have never seen vents in corners before, and here's why I think it would be better/worse/not matter.....

Answer (score 1):

When we design a space, we try to place vents 1) for cross ventilation, and 2) so no “draft” blows directly on a person.

Answer (score 0):

Windows leak air so typically heat vents are placed by windows so they can blow the warm air into the room and assist with circulation.

Comment: Vents are indeed often placed near windows, but not for leakage. The reason (at least in fairly modern homes) has more do do with comfort (cold air due to conduction) and condensation management.